The equation $xy-1 +(x^2-xy)y' = 0$ has an integrating factor depending only on $x$. Solve the equation.

The equation $$xy-1 +(x^2-xy)y' = 0$$ has an integrating factor depending only on $x$. Solve the equation.

Is there some simple way to solve the equation above? I ended up having to calculate some partial derivatives and the this was presented in an exam in which partial differential equations are not taught.

On rearranging the terms, the ODE becomes $$x\mathrm dy+y\mathrm dx=y\mathrm dy+\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$$ Can you proceed now?

The trick is $d(xy)=xdy+ydx$ and divide $x$ to obtain $d\ln(x)$.

As I have already commented, the given ODE can be converted into a bunch of exact differentials which can be integrated separately:
$$xy-1+(x^2-xy)y'=0$$
$$\implies (xy-1)\mathrm dx+(x^2-xy)\mathrm dy=0$$
Dividing throughout by $x$,
$$y\mathrm dx-\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}+x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dy=0$$
Recognizing that $x\mathrm dy+y\mathrm dx=\mathrm d(xy)$, we can write:
$$\mathrm d(xy)=\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}+y\mathrm dy$$
$$\implies\int\mathrm d(xy)=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}+\int y\mathrm dy$$
$$\therefore\boxed{xy=\frac{y^2}2+\ln|x|+C}$$
